# Launch embedded tomcat + war file from maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

I need to deploy following war that explained in maven:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>superwar</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
```

To embedded tomcat to be run it before integration test.

So when i do **mvn test**, i need to run embedded tomcat with pre-deployed war file from maven dependencies.

What maven configuration is the best to following?

Comment: Why must Maven solve this? Seems to me that the test code should be responsible for booting the embedded server.

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/run-mojo-features.html